# How to test toThrow exception?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, stenciljs

In my stencil component I am using `@Watch` to perform validation as below

```
  @Watch('name')
  validateName(newValue: string) {
    const isBlank = typeof newValue !== 'string' || newValue === '';
    console.log('AYE!', isBlank);
    if (isBlank) { throw new Error('name: required') };
  }
```

Now I would like to test this in jest

```js
it('throws error when name is not supplied', async () => {
    const { root } = await newSpecPage({ components: [MyComponent], html: '<my-component></my-component>' });

    expect(() => {
      root.name = '';
    }).toThrow(new Error('name: required'))  
  })
```

And the result I'm getting is as below

```
expect(received).toThrow(expected)

Expected message: "name: required"

Received function did not throw

  47 |     expect(() => {
  48 |       root.name = '';
> 49 |     }).toThrow(new Error('name: required'))  
     |        ^
  50 |   })
  51 | });
  52 | 

console.log
  AYE! true

  at MyComponent.validateName (src/xxx/my-component.tsx:31:13)
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I'm wondering how should I catch the error threw from `validateName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing a prop, you'll have to use the async `waitForChanges()`. You can check whether it throws by calling it and then using `rejects.toEqual(...)`. Also you'll have to return the `expect(...)` statement, otherwise your test will pass before the async code has finished (and you'd get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` in your console).

```js
it('throws error when name is not supplied', async () => {
  const { root, waitForChanges } = await newSpecPage({
    components: [MyComponent],
    html: '<my-component></my-component>'
  });

  root.name = '';

  return expect(waitForChanges()).rejects.toEqual(new Error('name: required'));
})
```

Comment: I prefer your solution than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `toThrow`, we can achieve the similar result via try catch block as below.

Also Stencil providdes `waitForChanges` method which allow us to alter the value of properties and wait for it to take effect

```js
it('throws error when name is not supplied', async () => {
    try {
      const { root, waitForChanges } = await newSpecPage({ components: [MyComponent], html: `<my-component name="xxx"></my-component>` });
      root.name = '';
      await waitForChanges()
    } catch (e) {
      expect(e).toStrictEqual(Error('name: required'));
    }
  })
```